# How to block click event for the parent element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a web page using `jQuery`. In this web page, there is a div tag that contains a `p` and a `button` tag.

The `HTML` code is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="attribute" style="border:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:#ccc">
        <p id="cell-content" style="display:inline">Id</p>
        <button id="remark-view" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the corresponding `JavaScript` code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#attribute").on('click', function(){
        console.log("click on the div attribute");
    });
    $("#attribute").on('dblclick', function(){
        console.log("double click on the div attribute");
    });
    $("#remark-view").on('click', function(){
        console.log("click on the button remark-view");
    });
});
```

As the code shows, a outer div has a p and button child element, and the outer div element listens on the single click and double click event while the inner button element listens on the single click event.

When I run the code in my browser and click on the button, the console shows that both click functions of the outer div and inner button element are called, which is against my purpose: only the click function of inner button should be called at this situation. Thus, is there any way to block the click event for the father element(in this case, outer div element).In other words, is there any way to stop passing the click event to the father element after the child element has handled it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**stopPropagation** function will stop the event from bubbling up the DOM.

```
$("#remark-view").on('click', function(event){
        console.log("click on the button remark-view");
        event.stopPropagation()
    });
```

From the jQuery documentation

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I use in one of my sites to do something similar to your problem. What the below code does is it prevents the middle `div` from closing if the button click is on that `div`.

```
//Function for the pop up with the background dimmer
  $(document).mouseup(function(x) {
    var container = $("#divContent"),
       dimmer = $('#bgDimmer');
     if (container.is(":visible")) {
       if (!container.is(x.target) //check if the target of the click isn't the container...
         && container.has(x.target).length === 0) {
          container.hide();
          dimmer.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Let try to relate to your code.

```
//Function for the pop up with the background dimmer
  $(document).mouseup(function(x) {
    var attribute = $('#attribute');
     if (attribute.is(":visible")) {
       if (!attribute.is(x.target) //check if the target of the click isn't the container...
         && attribute.has(x.target).length === 0) {
          console.log("click on the button remark-view");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The answer will work in my case, but I think it may be troublesome to use when the number of click listeners in the page increases. The method proposed by flyer may be better ?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of 'attribute.has(x.target).length === 0'. Could you explain its function?

Comment: It's to check if the container is filled or not in my case I don't think it would be needed for you. Agree with you on the better answer but posted this just as an option.